# What could a part of path of URL be called?

Tags: nouns, vocabulary, technical

http://example.com/test/test/coffee.html <- this is called a URL

/test1/test2/ <- this called a path

In this context, what would be a proper expression for a part of that path, such as test2?

Comment: I am not aware of an established name. The [relevant Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29) uses *path component*. In XPath (which is not about URLs, but uses a similar syntax), they are called *location steps*.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's called the **path segment**.

See: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396#section-3.3

> The path may consist of a sequence of path segments separated by a single
> slash "/" character.

Answer (score 0):

A URL (Uniform Resource Locator) is used to uniquely identify a resource over the web. URL has the following syntax:

> protocol://hostname:port/path/filename

So,  URL consists of 4 parts. The *path*, in fact, is nothing more than a **relative directory**. In your example, **test2** may either refer to a **directory** that has an index file or a file name changed by using URL rewrite function.